# Check foreground color of textblock

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to check my foreground color of my tapped textblock..

The code I have used is

```
If(textblock.foreground.equals(system.media.color.fromargb(100,0,255,0)))
Messagebox.show("got it ")";
```

This code is not working can any one help me??

Edited :- I want to check the color of 4 textblock..  I know the index value of the the textblock..

Comment: Whatever you're doing, most likely *no*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if(((sender as TextBlock).Foreground as SolidColorBrush).Color.Equals(Colors.Green))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It is green");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesnt work because TextBlock's Color property is a SolidColorBrush object. You can not make comparison between Color and SolidColorBrush, thats it.